# Batch File If modified date = yesterday date (run command)

Tags: date, batch-file, compare, dos

Ok, I'm using Rob Van der Woude yesterday.bat code along with some code that I've put together with the help of others posts here.

I have a file that I first want to see if it exists with yesterday's date, if true, then I'll do some other stuff.  The problem I am stuck on is comparing the filedate to "yesterday's" date.  When I echo them to screen, they both look exactly the same, but my batch file says they are not.  The first part of code is from yesterday.bat to show where I am inserting my code.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
Display the results
ECHO Format:     YYYYMMDD  (%LocalFormat%)
ECHO.==================================
CALL ECHO Yesterday:  %SortYest%  %yLocal%
ECHO Today:      %SortDate%  %Today%

:: Check if file gams1bu from yesterday exists
SET filename="B:\data\backup\gams1bu" 
IF NOT EXIST %filename% GOTO log 
FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf 

::This displays the results of the two variables
CALL ECHO %yLocal%
CALL ECHO %filedatetime:~0,-10%


IF %filedatetime:~0,-10% == %yLocal% goto same

goto notsame

:same
echo Dates the same, do some code here

goto next

:notsame
echo Dates NOT the same, do some code here
```

Even though the dates appear identical when I run this, the batch file goes to :notsame  ????

Answer (score 1):

The

```
SET filename="B:\data\backup\gams1bu" 
IF NOT EXIST %filename% GOTO log 
FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
```

doesn't seem to be setting filedatetime on my prompt (cmd.exe)

This will give you the current date in the format YYYYMMDD 20121128:

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do SET datestamp=%k%i%j
SET datestamp=20121128


C:\>echo %datestamp%
20121128
```

(The original command is from:)

http://www.sprint.net.au/~terbut/usefulbox/msdoscmds.htm

Hi

If you need to get the date of a file in YYYYMMDD format, you can do this:

Assume the name of the file is FILE_YOU_NEED.txt

```
for %a in (FILE_YOU_NEED.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %i in ('echo %FileDate%') do SET datestamp=%k%i%j
```

---

If your filedatetime variable has both the date and time you can try
comparing on a variable that only has the date, but not the time:

```
set FILEDATETIME=12/02/2012 13:45

echo %FILEDATETIME%
12/02/2012 13:45

set FILEDATEONLY=%FILEDATETIME:~0,10%

echo %FILEDATEONLY%
12/02/2012
```

Comment: The gams1bu file must exist for it to give the filedatetime.  This is important because I need the date the file was created so that I can compare it to yesterday's date.

Comment: Hi

If you need to get the date of a file in YYYYMMDD format, you can do this:

Assume the name of the file is FILE_YOU_NEED.txt

for %a in (FILE_YOU_NEED.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %i in ('echo %FileDate%') do SET datestamp=%k%i%j

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I've not been clear.  I determine yesterdays date in format MM/DD/YYYY.  I also have pulled the date a file was created.  It is in format MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm PM.  If the two are equal I want to return "Dates are the same"  

I have tried to truncate the file date by using

    %filedatetime:~0,-10%

But when I compare it still says that 

12/02/12 is not equal to 12/02/12.  I think that %filedatetime:~0,-10% just "hides the time" but that it is still being used in the comparison.  Is that right?  How can I get around that?

Comment: Why don't you set a new variable to the result of only the truncated part of filedatetime as in this:  C:\>set FILEDATETIME=12/02/2012 13:45

C:\>echo %FILEDATETIME%
12/02/2012 13:45

C:\>set FILEDATEONLY=%FILEDATETIME:~0,10%

C:\>echo %FILEDATEONLY%
12/02/2012

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but as I mentioned, even though it is truncating on the screen, I think it is still part of the value because it still states that is not equal.